# View Holder And custom list view items getting shuffled while scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview

I know there is a lot of similar questions out there but i cant find the mistake i am making,if anybody could help.
I am trying to display the values in an array list like a chat format but the array list items are getting misplaced on scrolling

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                        R.layout.chat_row, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
     holder.messageLeft = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.leftBox);
            holder.messageRight = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rightBox);
      convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            try { if (snd_id.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(appPref.getData("Uid"))) {
                holder.messageLeft.setText(snd_name.get(position)+":"+"\n"+chat.get(position));
                holder.messageLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.messageRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.messageRight.setText(snd_name.get(position)+":"+"\n"+chat.get(position));
                holder.messageRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.messageLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return convertView;

        }
```

here is the view holder class

```
private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView messageLeft;
        public TextView messageRight;
    }
```

Comment: i hav edited the question which now works fyn....thanks all for ur supports

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just include `holder.messageRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);` and  `holder.messageLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in your `if-else` statement.

```
 try {
        if (snd_id.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(appPref.getData("Uid"))) {
            holder.messageLeft.setText(snd_name.get(position)+":"+"\n"+chat.get(position));
            holder.messageLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.messageRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.messageRight.setText(snd_name.get(position)+":"+"\n"+chat.get(position));
            holder.messageRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.messageLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Let me know whether it works for you or not.

Answer (score 2):

You are pefroming `findViewById` every time..`ViewHolder` is not designed like that..Change your `if-else` condition like this and try..

```
   if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                R.layout.chat_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.messageLeft = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.leftBox);
        holder.messageRight = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.rightBox);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

And remove

```
 convertView.setTag(holder);
```

at the bottom

Comment: it didnt help its having same effect

Comment: whats happening when scroll

Comment: ya i made the corrections u told and also implemented what user370305 told and now it works fyn

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                    R.layout.chat_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
 holder.messageLeft = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.leftBox);
        holder.messageRight = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.rightBox);
  convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        try {
            if (snd_id.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(appPref.getData("Uid"))) {
                holder.messageLeft.setText(snd_name.get(position)+":"+"\n"+chat.get(position));
                holder.messageLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.messageRight.setText(snd_name.get(position)+":"+"\n"+chat.get(position));
                holder.messageRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;

    }
```

This is the efficient and correct approach to use a viewholder